# Ag-grid: how to implement filtering & sorting server side data?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I read documentation back and forth but did not find a single word about such basic feature.

Here is what I got so far:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.rowData = this.paymentMethodService.getPaymentMethods({});
  }
```

Getting data from Observable, note the empty `{}`, this is where I expect to pass filters, sorting, pagination info.

And here is a defined filter

```
{ headerName: 'Name', field: 'name' , sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter' }
```

The filter is applied to only those rows, that were displayed initially, while I need to path its data to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send to your API an information about `filter` and `sorting`. This is a rough example:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%" 
     class="ag-theme-balham"
     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
     [columnDefs]="yourColumns"
     (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
     #grid
></ag-grid-angular>
```

TypeScript:

```
public yourColumns: any[];
public rowData: any[];
public gridOptions: any;

@ViewChild('grid') grid: AgGridNg2;

this.yourColumns= [
      { headerName: 'One', field: 'one' },
      { headerName: 'Two', field: 'two' },
      { headerName: 'Three', field: 'three' }
    ];

this.gridOptions = {
  rowSelection: 'single',
  cacheBlockSize: 100,
  maxBlocksInCache: 2,
  enableServerSideFilter: false,
  enableServerSideSorting: false,
  rowModelType: 'infinite',
  pagination: true, 
  paginationAutoPageSize: true
};

 private getRowData(startRow: number, endRow: number): Observable<any[]> {
  //this code is included only for example. You need to move it to 
  //service
  let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
      .append('startRow', `${startRow}`)
      .append('endRow', `${endRow}`);

  return this.http.get(`${this.actionUrl}/GetAll`, {params: params})
      .pipe(
          map((res: any) => res.data)
      );
}

onGridReady(params: any) {
  console.log("onGridReady");
  var datasource = {
    getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
      this.getRowData(params.startRow, params.endRow)
                .subscribe(data => params.successCallback(data));

    }
  };
  params.api.setDatasource(datasource);

}
```